# How can I add pop-up (tooltip) definitions to words on a webpage when hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

My 250 page website has a glossary with many words and their definitions.  I would like to find a way to have the words in the glossary highlighted whenever they appear in the website text, and present a "tooltip" bubble showing the word's definition when hovered.  My website pages are all html -- I am not using a CMS.

I imagine I will need to use javascript for this.  I have looked and looked and have found javascript functions that can highlight certain text (ie wrap it in a span tag), but I do not know how to get this to iterate through an array of the words and include their definitions, and I'm not sure how resource-intensive this would be.

Is there a glossary type program in existence that would work for me without having to manually update every instance of each word throughout the entire website?  Or is there a fairly straightforward way to achieve this?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some of the code from your glossary?

Comment: The glossary, at this point, is just a text (html) document.  Words on a page.  Word: Definition, Word: Definition, etc.

Comment: I was more interested in the structure. Like are you using a definition list, paragraphs, etc.?

Comment: It's just <h2>Term</h2> <p>Definition</p>.  This can easily change, however.  I would be happy to put the terms and definitions into an xml spreadsheet or organize them into whatever sort of array one might need to get the above to work correctly.

Comment: Maybe just use pure and semantically correct HTML `<abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr>`. Browsers should automatically show tooltip.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using JQuery and having the glossary be a hidden div on the page, which  can be loaded using AJAX if you want.

```js
$("#glossary h2").each(function(index) {
  // Get the word and its definition.
  var word = $(this).text();
  var def = $("#glossary").find("p")[index].innerHTML;

  // Update all instances of that word in the content page with mouse over def.
  var contentHTML = $("#content").html();
  contentHTML = contentHTML.replace(new RegExp(word, 'g'), '<span title="' + def + '">' + word + '</span>');
  $("#content").html(contentHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  Will likes to hang out with Jim.
</div>

<div id="glossary" style="display:none;">
  <h2>Will</h2>
  <p>This is will's def.</p>
  <h2>Jim</h2>
  <p>This is jim's def.</p>
</div>
```

The above function assumes that you have a single `<p>` for every `<h2>` and that all contents of the `<p>` are part of the definition.

Comment: This is great, the only problem is that because it does a pass for each glossary term, if another term exists in the definition, it will nest the <font> tags inside the pervious <font> tag's title field.  So for example, if you have "This is will's def, it is different from Jim's, you'll run into problems.  It will end up looking like this:
Jim's.">Will likes to hang out with Jim.